# SVG Animation with CSS

Tags: css, animation, svg

iam currently trying to get a pinch to zoom animation done, with two different svg graphics. Is there a way, to transform or blend the first svg image into the second one, without using javascript, and maybe even without css?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Generator: Adobe Illustrator 18.1.0, SVG Export Plug-In . SVG Version: 6.00 Build 0)  -->
<svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="100px" height="100px" viewBox="-13 15 100 100" enable-background="new -13 15 100 100" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Ebene_11">
    <path fill="#010202" d="M78.5,93.1l0.8,1.4l-24.3,10l-0.4-1.4c0,0-0.8-2.6-3-4.2C49.7,97.4,29.7,81.2,30.2,75
        c0.3-3.2-0.8-5.4-1.6-7c-0.7-1.3-1.3-2.5-0.7-3.7c0.4-0.9,1.3-1.5,2.6-1.7c1.8-0.3,4.8,0.3,6.8,2.5c1.7,1.8,2.8,4.8,3.9,7.7
        c0.2,0.5,0.6,1.4,1,1.8c2.4,2.9,4.2,2.6,6,0.8c1.9-1.9,1.6-13.6-0.8-15c-1.8-1-4-1-6.8-1.9c-2.9-0.9-6.1-1.7-5.9-5.2
        c0.3-1.6,0.7-2.4,2.8-3.2c4.7-1.8,14.9-2.2,19.5,2.5c1.2,1.2,2.2,1.8,2.8,3.1c0.7-0.4,2.3-1.1,3.4-1.1c3.8,0,14.4,16.8,14.5,16.9
        c1.4,2.6-0.3,12.5-0.9,15.5C76.5,89.1,78.5,93.1,78.5,93.1z M56.6,100.9l18.8-7.8c-0.7-1.6-1.7-4.3-1.2-6.6
        c1.1-5.7,1.8-12.5,1.2-13.7c-1.7-3.1-10.1-14.7-12.2-15.5c-0.8,0-1.3,0.4-1.6,0.6c0.4,1.2,0.6,2.4,0.9,3.4c0.3,1.4,0.6,2.6,1,3.6
        c0.3,0.7,0,1.5-0.7,1.8c-0.7,0.3-1.5,0-1.8-0.7c-0.6-1.3-0.9-2.7-1.2-4.2c-0.3-1.2-0.5-2.5-1-3.7c0,0,0-0.1-0.1-0.1
        c-0.6-1.6-2-2.8-3.4-4.3c-3.7-3.7-12.8-3.3-16.6-1.8c-1.6,0.6-1.7,1.5-1.7,1.7c-0.1,1.1,1,1.6,4.1,2.6c3.2,1,7.8,0.8,9.6,4.6
        c0.3,0.6,0.9,3.6,0.9,4.6c0.4,8.3-0.2,10.8-4.3,13.2c-3.1,1.2-7.2-0.9-8.8-5.1c-1-2.6-2-5.4-3.3-6.8C34,65.4,32.3,65,31.3,65
        c-0.5,0-0.8,0.1-0.9,0.2c0.1,0.3,0.4,0.9,0.6,1.4c0.9,1.8,2.2,4.5,1.9,8.4c-0.4,4.6,15.3,17.5,20.3,21.4
        C55,98,56.6,100.9,56.6,100.9z">


  <animate id="animation1"
             attributeName="opacity"
             from="1" to="0" dur="2s"
             style="opacity:0"
           repeatCount="1" />



    </path>
</g>
<g>
    <path style="opacity:0" d="M76.9,87.2c0.5-2.9,2.1-12.7,0.8-15.2c-0.1-0.2-10.6-16.5-14.3-16.5c-0.9,0-1.6,0.2-2.3,0.5c-0.5-2.9-1-6-1.2-8.5
        c-0.4-5.3-1.3-8.5-4.9-8.9c-0.5-0.1-1.3,0-2.1,0.7c-2.1,2-3.3,8.3-2.8,16.2c0.6,12.3-1.1,20.5-3.2,21.3c-1.3,0.5-4-2.2-6.1-4.3
        c-2.1-2.2-4.3-4.4-6.6-5.4c-2.7-1.1-5.5-0.5-7.1,0.5c-1,0.7-1.6,1.6-1.6,2.6c0,1.3,1,2.1,2.1,3.1c1.3,1.1,3.2,2.6,4.3,5.6
        c2.1,5.7,18.3,18.5,20.2,20c2.2,1.6,3,4.1,3,4.1l0.4,1.4l23.7-10l-0.8-1.3C77.9,92.2,76.5,89.2,76.9,87.2z M57.2,100.9
        c-0.6-1.2-1.6-2.8-3.4-4.1C49,93,36.1,82.3,34.5,78.1c-1.3-3.7-3.6-5.5-5.1-6.8c-0.4-0.3-0.9-0.8-1.1-1c0.1-0.1,0.3-0.3,0.8-0.5
        c0.9-0.4,2.6-0.7,4.2,0c1.8,0.7,3.7,2.8,5.7,4.7c3.1,3.2,6,6.2,9,5c5.6-2.3,5.1-18.9,4.9-24c-0.5-8.9,1.2-13.5,2-14.1
        c0.9,0.1,2,0.4,2.4,6.4c0.4,5.9,2.3,15.5,3.9,19.2c0.3,0.7,1.1,1,1.8,0.7c0.7-0.3,1-1.1,0.7-1.8c-0.6-1.3-1.3-3.9-2-6.8
                               c0.3-0.3,0.8-0.6,1.6-0.7c2.1,0.8,10.3,12,12,15.1c0.6,1.1-0.1,7.8-1.1,13.4c-0.5,2.3,0.5,4.9,1.2,6.5L57.2,100.9z">


         <animate id="animation2"
             attributeName="opacity"
             from="0" to="1" dur="3s"
                  style="opacity:1"
                         repeatCount="1" />


    </path>
</g>
</svg>
```

Didnt fount much on the aether about it...thanks in advance

Comment: And where is your code?

Comment: currently i just have only a svg file with two path's in it. not much of a code

Comment: You should include the `svg` code in your question.

Comment: i added my code and i nearly got it. I fade out the first image and then fade in the second one. The Only Problem is now, that the first image should stay transparent and the second image should stay full visible.

and well maybe there is a way to do it more smoothly :)

Comment: You're using the correct approach. Keep playing with it until you get it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

got it

just added this to the first image

```
  <animate id="animation1"
            begin="0.8s"  
            attributeName="opacity"
            from="1" to="0" dur="0.5s"
            fill="freeze"/>
```

and this to the second one, and voila the animation is played once and stops then.

```
<animate id="animation2"
                begin="0.8s"
                attributeName="opacity"
                from="0" to="1" dur="1.3s"
                fill="freeze"/>
```

yay :)